# Telegram client operating on multiple thread

Tags: python, multithreading, api, telegram, telethon

I'm trying to attach to Telegram APIs to interact through such platform.

I need to send messages on multiple different threads, but I've not found any solution so far allowing me to do that.

Here you can find two sketch codes of my attempts to manage messages on different threads, using both `telethon` and `pyrogram` libraries.

So far, I've not found a solution yet.

**Telethon case**

```
import time
import threading

from telethon import TelegramClient, events

telegram_client = None

async def telethon_telegram_init(api_id, api_hash):
    global telegram_client
    client = TelegramClient('my_account', api_id, api_hash)
    await client.start()
    try: assert await client.connect()
    except: pass
    if not await client.is_user_authorized():
        client.send_code_request(phone_number)
        me = client.sign_in(phone_number, input('Enter code: '))
    client.parse_mode = 'html'
    telegram_client = client
    @telegram_client.on(events.NewMessage(incoming=True))
    async def telethon_telegram_receive(event):
        if event.is_private: await event.respond('Thank you for your message')

def telethon_telegram_send(to, message):
    global telegram_client
    while True:
        telegram_client.send_message(to, message)
        time.sleep(60)

# initiating the client object
telegram_client = telethon_telegram_init(api_id, api_hash)

# running the thread aimed to send messages
threading.Thread(target=telethon_telegram_send, args=('me', 'Hello')).start()
```

Results:

- initialization: ok
- message reception: not working (no errors are returned)
- message sending: not working (`AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'send_message'` returned)

**Pyrogram case**

```
import time
import threading

from pyrogram import Client, filters

def pyrogram_telegram_init(api_id, api_hash):
    client = Client('my_account', api_id, api_hash)
    @client.on_message(filters.private)
    async def pyrogram_telegram_receive(event):
        await event.reply_text(f'Thank you for your message')
    client.start()
    return client

def pyrogram_telegram_send(client, to, message):
    while True:
        client.send_message(to, message)
        time.sleep(60)

# initiating the client object
telegram_client = pyrogram_telegram_init(api_id, api_hash)

# running the thread aimed to send messages
threading.Thread(target=pyrogram_telegram_send, args=(telegram_client, 'me', 'Hello')).start()
```

Results:

- initialization: ok
- message reception: not working (no errors are returned)
- message sending: not working (no errors are returned)

**Update:**

**Attempts with asyncio**

I've also tried to use `asyncio`, as suggested by @Lonami. I've focused on the `telethon` library.
Nevertheless, please note that in my case, new Telegram messages are generated by a TCP server listening on the host, in a way similar to the simplified sketch code below.

Here is the code reporting my attempts.

```
import time
import asyncio

from telethon import TelegramClient, events

RECIPIENT = 'me'

api_id = '...'
api_hash = '...'

telegram_client = None

# server management part

from socketserver import ThreadingMixIn, TCPServer, StreamRequestHandler
class ThreadingTCPServer(ThreadingMixIn, TCPServer): pass

class ServerSample(StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        message = 'New connection from %s:%s' % self.client_address
        print(message)
        self.server.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self.server.queue.put_nowait, message)
        # also tried with the following:
        #self.server.queue.put_nowait(message)

async def initialize_server(loop, queue):
    with ThreadingTCPServer(('127.0.0.1', 8080), ServerSample) as server:
        server.loop = loop
        server.queue = queue
        server.serve_forever()

async def telethon_telegram_init(api_id, api_hash):
    global telegram_client
    client = TelegramClient('my_account', api_id, api_hash)
    await client.start()
    try: assert await client.connect()
    except Exception as e: print(str(e))
    if not await client.is_user_authorized():
        client.send_code_request(phone_number)
        me = client.sign_in(phone_number, input('Enter code: '))
    client.parse_mode = 'html'
    telegram_client = client
    @telegram_client.on(events.NewMessage(incoming=True))
    async def telethon_telegram_receive(event):
        if event.is_private: await event.respond('Thank you for your message')
    return telegram_client

async def telethon_telegram_generate(loop, queue, t):
    loop.call_soon_threadsafe(queue.put_nowait, 'Hello from direct {} call'.format(t))

async def main():
    global telegram_client
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    # initiating the Telegram client object
    await telethon_telegram_init(api_id, api_hash)
    # initializing the server (non blocking)
    loop.create_task(initialize_server(loop, queue))
    # creating a new message (non blocking)
    loop.create_task(telethon_telegram_generate(loop, queue, 'non blocking'))
    # creating a new message (blocking)
    loop.run_in_executor(None, telethon_telegram_generate, loop, queue, 'blocking')
    # managing the queue
    while True:
        message = await queue.get()
        print("Sending '{}'...".format(message))
        await telegram_client.send_message(RECIPIENT, message)
        time.sleep(1)

asyncio.run(main())
```

In this case, to trigger the generation of a new Telegram message from the TCP server itself, it is needed to launch a `curl` command like the following one:

> curl http://localhost:8080

Nevertheless, results are not promising.

Results:

- initialization: ok for `telethon_telegram_init` and `initialize_server`, apparently not working for both `telethon_telegram_generate` method calls
- message reception: not working (no errors are returned)
- message sending: not working (no errors are returned)
- additional notes: after the `curl` command is executed, a `New connection from 127.0.0.1:<random_port>` message is printed, but no Telegram messages are sent

Comment: Do you *need* threads? If not, I recommend reading through `asyncio`'s documentation. You can do everything (and more) with `asyncio` than `threading`.

Comment: I need threads, as I am also using an external library (used as the core library for my software) making use of threads. This is because I've used threads in my sketches.

Comment: My recommendation is you create a thread for `asyncio`. In there, you can use Telethon. You should safely communicate with the thread with messages and the tools `asyncio` provides. Telethon itself should never be used directly outside that dedicated thread.

Comment: Thank you. Could you provide me a sample sketch?

Comment: I recommend you search around for "how to use `threading` and `asyncio`", I'm sure someone's asked that before. Once you learn to do that, you can add Telethon to the mix.

Comment: Just updated the question, with my (unsuccessful) attempts.

Comment: `await asyncio.sleep` should be used instead of `time.sleep` when inside an `async` context.